# Stuck in Dangerous Minds

Tags: fallout-4

I'm stuck in the Memory Den in Fallout 4. When I finish the walk among Kellogs memories in Dangerous Minds, the doctor won't talk to me when I get out of the memory lounger. Is there any way to fix this or is there at patch to correct the glitch? I've been playing for 30 days now - and can't proceed with the main quest because of this. HELP!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an autosave right before you enter the memories, check your save files and then you may be able to just walk through the memories again, it may take a few minutes, but hopefully it will fix your problem. (And it's defiantly better than messing up your game with console commands)

Comment: Sidenote: If you have to do it again, like @DBS said, you can just run through. You don't have to listen to Kelloggs life story, thats just for fluff. The only important sequenze (which you have to watch) is the last one.

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered this. There's a bug in the quest where saving and loading in Kellogg's memories breaks the quest script. If you have a saved game (like an auto-save) from before entering the memories, reload it and go through the whole sequence without saving. As Bounce said in his comment, you don't have to watch all of the memories; you can just walk through to the end.

If you have no older saved games, you can try to force the quest to advance using a console command. This one might make it possible to talk to Dr. Amari:

```
SetStage MQ202 310
```

And this one should force the quest to complete:

```
SetStage MQ202 320
```

Comment: I am stuck in this as well, I'm playing the PS4 verison though :(

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's a way to get to the console on PS4. I'm surprised the bug hasn't been patched by now...

Comment: I'm a bit worried that im screwed as i have no save games before i entered the memory area, I suppose I could just finish all the side quests lol.

Comment: @AdamHaun Year 2018, and this bug is still there. Bethesda is so lame in this regard (I mean, fixing ancient GAME-BREAKING bugs).

Comment: I think they typically stop patching bugs within a year after they come out since the fans are "nice" enough to do it for them. It looks like the Unofficial Fallout 4 Patch hasn't fixed this yet. Maybe it's harder than it sounds.